# how can I restart redmine?

Tags: reboot, redmine

Redmine has to be restarted after a plugin installation.

How can I do that on linux? Does it mean to restart my web server (nginx in my case)? Or do I have to do something else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Restart your webserver. How to do that depends on your webserver you installed Redmine in, and your Linux distribution. For Apache on Debian, I'd do a:

```
# /etc/init.d/apache restart
```

Comment: I run redmine on ngix and Ubunbu. Well if restarting webserver is what I need to do that I know how to restart web server already.

Answer (score 14):

```
touch /path/to/redmine/tmp/restart.txt
```

Redmine will restart at the next page request. This is often the only way if you're on an instance where you don't have permission to restart Apache (shared hosting, etc).

Comment: This seems to be the way how Phusion Passenger works: whenever you touch the `tmp/restart.txt` file, Passenger restarts all the Rails processes. I didn't manage to restart apache this way though, you would need something like `sudo apache2ctl restart`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to stop WebRick by doing a Ctrl+C, if running Mongrel you sould try

> mongrel_rails stop

Comment: don't I have to  restart it? Just `stop` is good enough?

Comment: Stop is not good enough, my bad there... You should a start after the stop command, or a restart.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu (10.04) installs redmine (0.9.3) with passenger. It is passenger that really does restart application using (in /usr/share/redmine):

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

However, there is another point there. In config/environment.rb, the setting

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
```

must be changed to:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Reference: http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/4240

I found it was too much hassle to setup Gmail SMTP, so I've rather setup exim4.

Answer (score 0):

Debian > systemctl restart redmine